# Difficulty including integrated authentication in API call outside an Excel workbook using Python

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-chrome, authentication

I have a specific scenario in my organization where I use a laptop to access an API dashboard through a Chrome window. Within the Chrome window, I can make queries to the API and also download a workbook that contains an automated organizational authentication. Within the workbook, there is a specific cell that displays the URL used for the background query. However, I've noticed that this URL only contains the necessary filters for the API call, without any authentication parameters included. Surprisingly, the query runs seamlessly within the workbook, implying that the workbook has some integrated authentication mechanism that is transparent to me. The problem arises when I try to replicate this functionality outside the workbook or outside the Citrix-generated Chrome window. Now, when I attempt to replicate the same API call outside the workbook or within the Citrix Chrome window, I face the following challenges:

I'm unsure how to incorporate the integrated authentication mechanism in the API call. The URL provided in the workbook lacks any explicit authentication parameters.
Without the authentication parameters, my API calls are met with authentication errors, preventing me from retrieving the desired data. I am seeking guidance and assistance on how to overcome this hurdle and include the integrated authentication in the API call outside the workbook or within the Citrix-generated Chrome window. Is there a specific method or technique that I should employ to ensure the necessary authentication parameters are included? Any advice, examples, or suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help!